# What could these gelatinous deposits on organic Brussels sprouts be?

Tags: identification, vegetables, organic

I recently purchased a full stem of Brussels sprouts grown without pesticides in Kanagawa, Japan. Upon preparing the sprouts for cooking, I noticed that many of the sprouts, from the lower part of the stem up to about the middle, had some small, gelatinous deposits on their leaves.

I didn't notice any actual critters crawling over the sprouts.

What could these deposits be? Fungus, insect, plant? And are they dangerous if not dealt with properly while preparing the sprouts as a meal?

[image: wide shot of affected leaf]
[image: detail of affected leaf]
[image: secondary detail of affected leaf]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like honeydew to me. Apparently, the farm of your Brussels sprout provider was infested by aphids. They literally shit 'sweet' honeydew.

Read more here: [Honeydew (secretion)/ Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeydew_(secretion))

Comment: And, in fact, sweet to eat and harmless.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I agree. Just the idea itself of eating makes people disgust,  taboo is in what we see. Biblical literature suggests the tribes of Israel had it during their Exodus, it was drawn in comparison to Nectar of Life.

Comment: Thank you for the info. This does seem to match what I observed. I had suspected it was the output of some kind of insect, but I was surprised that I couldn't find any living specimens or clear evidence of them having eaten the plant.